# Symlink(): no such file or directory because public folder is in a different directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-storage

I'm working on an application and wanted to implement image uploading to my application. Now when I want to create the symbolic link for my files, I get the following error:

```
ErrorException : symlink(): No such file or directory

Exception trace:
symlink("/home/user/private/application/storage/app/public", "/home/user/private/application/public/storage")
```

I know what the cause of this is, but i don't know how to fix and/or have a workaround for it.

I have my public folder in my html_root directory, and have the rest of the application in a directory outside of my html_root. In this case `/home/user/private/application`.

when I use `php artisan storage:link` it tries to find the public folder in my 'private' directory, but can't find it because my public folder is in html_root.

Comment: If you changed the folder structure of Laravel, you can't expect functions that rely on that structure to work properly. In this case, I would look at the code for the `storage:link` command (`Illuminate\Foundation\Console\StorageLinkCommand`), duplicate to a custom command and modify as required.

Comment: As only the public contents should be in the html_root i thought it to be also good (for structure purpose) to place the rest in another directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by placing my html_root content back to my private folder in `/home/user/private/application` and creating a symlink of my public folder that goes to my `/home/user` and renaming the `/home/user/public` folder to `/home/user/html_root` (and keeping the symlink intact).

So i remain with the official Laravel directory structure and make a faux (symlink) of the public folder.

With this i can use the `php artisan storage:link` normally without creating a custom Command.